# I am having trouble with TextField in Jetpack Compose and Material 3

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I'm new to compose, and I'm mostly trying to follow along with tutorials to get a hang of the various components.  I have a simple function that just defines a text field, and I can't get it to compile if I add some parameters.  Here is an example:

```
package com.example.jettip.components

import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun InputField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    valueState: MutableState<String>,
    labelId: String,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    isSingleLine: Boolean = true,
    keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    imeAction: ImeAction = ImeAction.Default,
    onAction: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,

) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    TextField(
        value = valueState.value,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        modifier = modifier,
        enabled = enabled,
        //keyboardType = keyboardType,
        keyboardActions = onAction,
        )


}
```

This compiles fine, but if I uncomment the keyboardType parameter, I get errors.

First of all, this line has an error on it:

```
onValueChange = { text = it },
```

The "it" parameter is red with the error, "Unresolved reference: it"
This makes no sense to me, unless I have something really wrong configured in my Studio

I also get the error "None of the functions can be compiled with the arguments supplied"
Maybe keyboardType needs to go with another parameter, but I can't tell from the documentation.

I started with a blank activity project created by Studio.  I have the latest Studio.  Do I need to do something with my gradle files?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, does anyone know why I have to accept experimental M3 before I can use a text field?  I started with the default project built by Studio, and I would think that would have the latest dependencies.  Do I need to change something in my Gradle file?

Comment: @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)

Comment: as it sad when you click on that "ExperimentalMaterial3Api" -> "This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future." It still an "Experimental" usecase.

Answer (score 0):

For this it more like a stateful component

> var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

If you wish to use it should be try :

> { valueState.value = it } // For delegate

*base on the Android Docs it does mention delegate to the caller to update it value.*

**Note:** For **M3** things it's not much different from **M2**

It may be got the same name but it may need another wrapper for it.

Try This code below for M3

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @Composable
    fun InputField(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        valueState: MutableState<String> = remember { mutableStateOf("") },
        labelId: String,
        enabled: Boolean = true,
        isSingleLine: Boolean = true,
        keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
        imeAction: ImeAction = ImeAction.Default,
        onAction: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
        ) {
        TextField(
            value = valueState.value,
            onValueChange = { valueState.value = it },
            modifier = modifier,
            enabled = enabled,
            keyboardActions = onAction,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = keyboardType)
        )
    }
```

Comment: That worked.  Instead of "keyboardType = keyboardType" I used "keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = keyboardType)".  I'm still not sure why the original way fails and why it causes the error on the "onValueChange = { text = it }" line.

Comment: Please check the type of that "text'.